# The tilde operator in Scala

Tags: scala

What does the ~ do in this bit of Scala?

For example:

```
scala> val apple = 1
apple: Int = 1

scala> ~apple
res0: Int = -2
```

What did that worm do to my apple?

Comment: @GeneT Link is broken

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Firstly, some meta-advice. Any time you're wondering how the compiler expands some syntactic sugar, infers a type, or applies an implicit conversion, use `scala -Xprint:typer -e <expr>` to show you what happened.

```
scala -Xprint:typer -e "val a = 2; ~a"

...
private[this] val a: Int = 2;
private <stable> <accessor> def a: Int = $anon.this.a;
$anon.this.a.unary_~
```

Okay, a prefix `~` is expanded to a regular method invocation of `unary_~`.

From the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> **6.12.1 Preﬁx Operations**
>
> A preﬁx operation op e consists of a preﬁx operator op, which must be one of the identiﬁers `+`, `-`, `!` or `~`.
>   The expression `op e` is equivalent to the postﬁx method application
>   `e.unary_op`.
>
> Preﬁx operators are different from normal function applications in
>   that their operand expression need not be atomic. For instance, the
>   input sequence `-sin(x)` is read as `-(sin(x))`, whereas the function
>   application negate `sin(x)` would be parsed as the application of the
>   inﬁx operator sin to the operands negate and (x).

That means that the prefix operators aren't restricted to built in types, they can be used on your own types (although it's not a good idea to go crazy with this power!)

```
scala> object foo { def unary_~ = "!!!" }
defined module foo

scala> ~foo
res0: java.lang.String = !!!
```

So, what of your question? You can checkout the index of the ScalaDoc for the standard library for [methods starting with `u`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#index.index-u). The [nightly ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Int) has some recently added documentation for this method.

```
the bitwise negation of this value
Example:
~5 == -6
// in binary: ~00000101 ==
//             11111010
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and references.

Comment: broken link for nightly ScalaDoc!

Answer (score 18):

`~` is the bitwise not operator when applied to integers.  It's easiest to see in hex:

```
scala> "%x".format( ~0x7F )
res0: String = ffffff80
```

Comment: +1 for confirming it's the bitwise not operator. I was fiddling around with printing the binary string when you answered. Apologies that I can accept only one answer.